# Warning when casting from supposedly same size types

Tags: c, casting

I can't figure this warning out. It says I am casting a MY_KEY to a HKEY of greater size, but they would appear to be the same size (32 bits)?

```
//test.c
//compile as C
//compile with warning level 4

#include <windows.h>

typedef enum MY_KEY
{
    //from WinReg.h :
    //#define HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT ((HKEY)(ULONG_PTR)((LONG)0x80000000))

    //ULONG_PTR cast to avoid 'constant expression is not integral' error
    //(caused by HKEY being a HANDLE, and so a void*)
    MY_KEY_1 = (ULONG_PTR)HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,
} MY_KEY;

void Func1(HKEY b)
{
    b;
}

void Func2(MY_KEY a)
{
    //produces warning C4306:
    //'type cast' : conversion from 'MY_KEY' to 'HKEY' of greater size
    Func1((HKEY)a);
}
```

(C code, VS2005, warning level 4.)

Comment: MY_KEY is a 32-bit signed int, so they are of the same size but not the same signedness. I don't know VS, so I'm not sure if this is what's causing the problem.

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, I think you're right. If I change the last line to `Func1((HKEY)(ULONG_PTR)a);` the warning goes away! I was fiddling and found that if I change it to `Func1((HKEY)MY_KEY_1);` the warning also goes away, but that doesn't help me because the call needs to use `Func2`'s argument. Is using `Func1((HKEY)(ULONG_PTR)a);` the correct way to solve this then?

Comment: Can you drop the cast? In `C` casts are often unnecessary. Use `Func1(a);` and let the compiler do the conversion based on the function prototype. If the compiler can't do it implicitly, chances are that doing it explicitly with a cast is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: The sensible thing to do would probably be to typedef HKEY MY_KEY. Enums are bad, since they default to the standard int type of the system.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that MY_KEY is a ULONG_PTR to an HKEY. You are type casting it to an actual HKEY when you pass it to function 1, which is a bad idea. If you want an HKEY, why are you not using an HKEY directly? Unless you need a pointer for some reason, in which case, pass along the data that the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: MY_KEY is not a ULONG_PTR, it is a **signed int**.

Comment: To clarify: HSOMETHING in Windows notation means "handle to", which is just a weirder way of saying pointer. So HKEY in this case, is a pointer to a KEY.